# Pasting a Singlar Row Into Multiple Active Rows/Cells Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to copy and paste the information and format of a single row into multiple selected(active) rows using VBA.

My current code is:

```
Sub Breakers()

  Worksheets("Temp").Range("A7:AJ7").Copy
  ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
  ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

My issue is that when I run the code the single row is copied into only the first row of the multiple rows that were selected.

I am copying the row from one worksheet into another.

I am new to the world of automating excel and would greatly appreciate and help. Thank you!

Comment: You can use the `Selection` object to copy to all selected rows

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Sub Breakers()
Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Worksheets("Destiny") 'change this with name of destiny worksheet

Dim i As Long

Worksheets("Temp").Range("A7:AJ7").Copy

For i = 2 To 10 Step 1 'change 2 and 10 to first and last row where pasting. Change A with column you want
    wk.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    wk.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i

Set wk = Nothing

End Sub
```

You were close. I just added a loop to paste several times trough rows.

In this example, the row will be pasted trough rows `2:10`